# Не погу  получить $_FILES из формы хтмл

Tags: html, php, javascript, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, делаю для себя чтобы разобраться форму регистрации пользователя  ну и загружаю туда картинку профиля. но не могу почему-то получить имя загруженной картинки через $_POST,  предаёт пустое значение.

Т.е передаются все значения имена пароли выполняются проверки нужные и заносятся в базу, а вот var_dump(  $_FILES['files']); выдаёт NULL.

загрузчик взят с  [гитхаба](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

вот код страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Generic page styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload.css">
    <style>
    .well{
    margin-top: 240px;
    margin-left: 330px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

 <body>
  <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="well col-xs-4 ">
             <legend>Registration</legend>
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="registration.php">                 
                      <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-12" placeholder="Login" name="login" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$">                 
                      <br><input type="email" class="form-control col-xs-12" placeholder="e-mail" name="email">
                      <br><input type="password" class="form-control col-xs-12" placeholder="Password" name="password"> 
                      <br><input type="password" class="form-control col-xs-12" placeholder="Password" name="password2">    
                      <br><input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-12" placeholder="Question" name="question" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$">
                      <br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Registration</button>
    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Select Photo...</span>
    <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files" multiple>
    </span>
                </form>
            <div>
       <div>       
  </div>
 <br>
<div class="container col-xs-12">
    <!-- The global progress bar -->
    <div id="progress" class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
    <div id="files" class="files"></div>
</div>
 <br><a href="http://localhost/authorisation.html">Авторизация</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверить значения в **php.ini** для:

- file_uploads
- post_max_size
- upload_max_file_size

Убедиться, что имеются права на запись соотв. директорий. Нет пробелов в пути у этих директорий. Проверить, не "портит" ли что-то JS при отправке.

Answer (score 1):

Файлы, загружаемые на сервер содержатся не в `$_POST`, а в `$_FILES`.

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Вы правы, но всё равно получаю NULL

Answer (score 0):

А что вы хотите от файла узнать?
Например, чтобы узнать имя файла на клиенте, то echo $_FILES['files']['name'];
Вам уже **fori1ton** написал ссылку на официальный мануал.

> http://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: да всё хорошо бы но структуру $_FILES я получаю пустую , в этом то и проблема .